# R reciprocal edges in igraph in R

Tags: r, graph, nodes, bidirectional, igraph

I am working with graphs in R. I am currently using igraph and I would like to be able to plot bidirectional edges "reciprocal edges" of a graph. So far I've seen it is possible to plot "bidirectional" graphs but not reciprocal edges, for example: E(1,3) and E(3,1) could potentially be represented as a bidirectional edge <-->, but instead I would like to plot two parallel edges one pointing to the opposite direction of the other || . 
There exist in Rgraphviz an option when plotting "plot(rEG, recipEdges = "distinct")" that makes this, but I like more how plots look like on igraph. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `igraph`, you can use the edge attribute `curved` to curve the edges you want.

For example, here is a graph based small adjacency matrix:

```
library("igraph")
adj <- matrix(c(
    0,1,1,
    1,0,1,
    0,0,0),3,3,byrow=TRUE)

library("igraph")
G <- graph.adjacency(adj)
```

The edge between node 0 and 1 is bidirected (Actually, it isn't, it are two edges and they just look like a bidirected edge because they are straight).:

```
plot(G)
```

To change this, we can use the edgelist:

```
E <- t(apply(get.edgelist(G),1,sort))

E(G)$curved <- 0
E(G)[duplicated(E) | duplicated(E,fromLast =TRUE)]$curved <- 0.2

plot(G)
```

---

Another option is my package, where this is the default behavior:

```
library("qgraph")
qgraph(adj)
```

which can be suppressed with the `bidirectional` argument.

Comment: Thanks so much, I see you can even set up the separation between parallel edges, that is great.

Answer (score 2):

Try `plot(graph, edge.curved=TRUE)`. It definitely works in igraph 0.6, and it may also work in igraph 0.5.4 (not sure when it was added).

Comment: this is great, what I liked of @sachaepskamp 's answer is that you are able to modify between-edges separation, thanks to both.